# Filas duplicadas en JPA

Tags: java, spring

Estoy realizando la consulta a mi entidad "EngBookModel", al mostrar los datos, Spring me indica que tengo filas repetidas.

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Duplicate row was found and `ASSERT` was specified
```

Consulta Hibernate generada:

```
Hibernate: 
select
    e1_0.genre,
    e1_0.abreviation,
    e1_0.id,
    e1_0.name,
    e1_0.testament 
from
    bible_aa_books e1_0 
where
    e1_0.genre=?
```

No se que pueda estar haciendo mal o que anotación me haga falta.

Este es el código.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="bible_aa_books")
public class EngBookModel {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private String genre;
private String name;
private String abreviation;
private String testament;
private String id;

 *Getters and Setters ...*

}
```

En mi base de datos tengo.

[image: Tabla bible_aa_books]

Encontré este post en ingles pero no ha solucionado mi problema

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73826361/spring-jpa-joint-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error te indica que hay un id duplicado.
Estás usando el campo `genre` como identificador, que es un campo que se repite.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private String genre;
```

Y esa es la causa del error.

Deberías usar la columna id y anotarla como identificador de esta forma:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private String id; //uso String porque así está mapeado en tu código
```

Nota aparte, deberías verificar si id en la base de datos es número o texto. En caso de ser número esto sería:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id; // o Integer
```